# Kotlin + Dagger 2: RuntimeException: has no zero argument constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, code-injection, dagger-2

When I try to inject a class via constructor in a `Kotlin` class I am getting this exception.

I have been reading about ways to solve it in `Java` by adding an empty constructor to the class that gets the injection.

However, it does not seem to be possible (or I do not how) to do it in `Kotlin`.

The code that throws the exception has nothing out of normal...just a simple injection.

Here it is a piece of the code with the injection that throws exception:

```
class RemoteService @Inject constructor(
        @SongListRepo private val songListRepo: SongListRepo): MainBaseService() {
...
...
...
}
```

And of course the `SongListRepo` is provided by a module in the usual Dagger 2 way.

**-------- EDIT: ---------**

After some help and comments from @Demigod the code looks like this

```
class RemoteService (): MainBaseService() {

    lateinit var songLR : SongListRepo
    @Inject constructor(@SongListRepo songListRepo: SongListRepo) : this(
    {
        this.songLR = songListRepo
    }
```

Problem now is that **secondary constructor never gets initialized**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the error you're getting is related to this `Service` (I think like `Fragment` they must have a zero argument constructor, so that the platform would be able to re create them)? If **yes** than you might use an on demand injection, like:

```
class RemoteService: MainBaseService() {

    @Inject
    @SongListRepo 
    private lateinit var songListRepo: SongListRepo

    init {
        // Something like this
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    }
}
```

Or, anyway you can add additional constructors like:

```
class RemoteService constructor(): MainBaseService() {

     private lateinit var songListRepo: SongListRepo? = null

     @Inject constructor(@SongListRepo songListRepo: SongListRepo):this() {
         this.songListRepo = songListRepo
     }
}
```

More about constructors [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

Comment: hi thanks, second solution gives me problems `val` not allowed in secondary constructor, same as `private`. First solution just does not work in Kotlin, int tells "property must be initialized or be abstract"

Comment: I'll edit my answer, you're right about the second one, and on the first one I just forgot to use `lateinit`

Comment: i will give it a try but im pretty sure that `lateinit` will not accept nullables in kotlin

Comment: It doesn't matter for `lateinit var` null it is or not. Nullability is customized with `?` meaning that `SongListRepo` cannot be `null`, but `SongListRepo?` can. The `lateinit var` modifier just simply allows you to not init variable at the object creation time. But you must be sure to use it after initialization, cause you will get an exception if you try to use `lateinit var` before it is initialized.

Comment: in the second solution, how should the `lateinit` be initialized?, i guess it is done itself via the injection or? am i too wrong? :)

Comment: Yes, it is done through an injection, but only when second constructor (with parameters) is called.